# Apigee-127: Unable to deploy to on premise Apigee from Apigee-127, 303 error

Tags: apigee, swagger, apigee127

I am trying to deploy my Mock API to Apigee Edge from Apigee-127 command line. This is an On-Prem instance & so I have a VPN going to give me access. However Once I get on & try to deploy the API. I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\sgs>a127 account create myTestAccount
[?] Provider? apigee
[?] Do you have an account? Yes
[?] Base URI? (https://api.enterprise.apigee.com) https://enterprise.apigee.com/
[?] Base URI? https://enterprise.apigee.com/platform/#/my-Company/
[?] Organization? myCompany
[?] User Id? my.Name@myCompany.com
[?] Password? *********
[?] Environment? test
[?] Virtual Hosts? default,secure
Ensuring Apigee Remote Proxy is in place...
Error: Account creation failed. Please try again.
{ [Error] statusCode: 303 }
```

Any ideas what I could try different?

With Regards

S

Comment: You need to find out the statusCode' s meaning, it seems the details you provided are correct so try to find out more about what' s going on by finding the meaning of status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your "Base URI" value. This needs to be the URI of your management endpoint and isn't related to your particular organization. (For example, you can see above that the default for the Apigee hosted environment is https://api.enterprise.apigee.com.)

Answer (score 0):

The Base URL should be something like `{org-name}.login.apigee.com/oauth/token`. There are other tools like [ADT](https://github.com/ashishkpathak/adt) which can help deploy apiproxies/shared-flows.